# Regex now finding all matching strings

Tags: java, regex

I am using this regex `("http:|"https:)\/\/.*\/content\/amc\/tdd\/.*?"` to find all the urls which starts with http or https and contains /content/amc/tdd
But for the text

```
"<a id='cdq_element_175_link' href='http://google.com' data-href='edit' >
<img src=\"http://localhost:8080/content/amc/tdd/abc/download_1.jpeg? 
ch_ck=1548843340209\" alt=\"\" id=\"element_175\" style=\"height: 135.575px; width: 135.575px;\" data-href=\"edit\">
<img src=\"http://localhost:8080/content/amc/tdd/abc/download_1.jpeg?ch_ck=1548843340209\" alt=\"\" id=\"element_175\" style=\"height: 135.575px; width: 135.575px;\" data-href=\"edit\">
</a>"
```

I am not getting two strings which matches the pattern, instead I am getting the complete string starting from first instance to the last.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your wildcard match is greedy. Add a `?` after the first `*` so it stops when it finds match.

Answer (score 2):

Because inside your regex `.*` is greedy match, it will eat all your string.

You should change it to `.*?`
Like this:

```
("http:|"https:)\/\/.*?\/content\/amc\/tdd\/.*?"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this Regex:

```
"https?:\/\/(?:[^\/]*\/)*?content\/amc\/tdd[^"]*"
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fo2FqF/2)**

**Explanation:**

- `"https?:\/\/` - matches `"http://` or `"https://`
- `(?:[^\/]*\/)*?` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character which is not a `/` followed by `/`. This subpattern is repeated 0 or more times, as least as possible.
- `content\/amc\/tdd` - matches `content/amc/tdd`
- `[^"]*"` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a `"` followed by `"`